# Stuck with my log4j properties file and getting the output into logging.log?

Tags: java, log4j

This is my log4j.properties file :

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, Console

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File= C:\\Users\\adel\\Desktop\\Misc_Stuff\\Java_Code\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

And my Java class is a simple HelloWorld :

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class HelloWorldLog4J {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("pre_loggerDOTinfo");

        logger.info("Hello, World!");

        System.out.println("post_loggerDOTinfo");

    }

}
```

I'm not sure why it is not working. Someone said I need to use either `\\` or `/` for the path to log4j.appender.file.File , and I tried both , but still it won't work.

Should I use Eclipse rather than manually doing it ?

Answer (score 2):

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, Console
```

'ALL' stands for log level and 'Console' stands for appender name in this line. You want to redirect your logs to 'file' appender that you created below so you need to change this line to:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, file
```